# Make Android Screen Rotation configurable application wide

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

I have a switch in my Android app settings to turn screen rotation on and off - just the way the user likes it to be.

But it does not disable in my app. I tried

```
_activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

but rotation is still on. I know I can do this in the manifest file, but I want it to be configurable and not static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` inside `onCreate()` method in your activity.

Or since that method is not always called you could put it in the `onResume()` method of your activity.

[image: activity lifecycle]